# Connect to mysql on a different server

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Im trying to connect to mysql database server from another server.  The following are configurations on both servers.

> Server 1:
>   I installed xampp with php and apache services and it has the following ip 172.x1.x1.x1
>
> Server 2:
>   I installed mysql and it has the following ip 172.x1.x1.x2.

the following is the connection script I am using to connect to the database

```
<?php
    //Database connection constants
    define("DATABASE_HOST", "172.x1.x1.x2");
    define("DATABASE_USERNAME", "root");
    define("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DATABASE_NAME", "management");
?>
```

The above script is in a file called app_config.php and its located in server 1
The following script is in a file called connect.php and its also located in server 1

```
<?php
require 'app_config.php';
$connect_error = 'Sorry we\'experiencing connection problems.';
$table_error = 'Table not found';
mysql_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD)
or die($connect_error);
```

mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME)
    or die($table_error);
?>
 now when I try to connect I get the following error

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'hr1.saqa.co.za' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\functions\database\connect.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function handle_error() in C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\functions\database\connect.php on line 5

It will be awsome if you can help me guys.

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_*` and port your code to either `mysqli` or `PDO`. mysql is obosolete, and it will most likely be completely removed in the next major release.

Comment: Try this one :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822902/access-xampp-localhost-from-internet

Comment: You also need to set it so the user is allowed to connect to the database from remote IP addresses, or set a specific IP address.

Comment: @VladPreda I'l eventually move away from mysql_* but I am still new to php and the book I was reading still uses that script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your database server is different from your php/apache server you need to specify the hostname as `172.x1.x1.x2` in mysql-php connection string.

Also make sure that mysql user `root` have remote connection permission. Other wise mysql-server will not allow your `root` user to login remotely. i.e. from your server1.

You can make sure that from `mysql.user` table.

```
mysql> select Host,User from user where User = "root";
+------------+------+
| Host       | User |
+------------+------+
| 127.0.0.1  | root |
| ::1        | root |
| localhost  | root |
| sgeorge-mn | root |
| %          | root |
+------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

`%` means any host.

To create a user with remote connection permission, use following `mysql` query:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
```

Comment: I updated my script with the correct ip, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: see my answer part about `mysql.user`

Comment: Just a further explanation, these servers both run windows server 2008 r2

Comment: do I run this sql command in the sql database or the webserver ?

Comment: Off course, from DB server. From webserver you can't run `sql` query. ;-). Also don't for give `GRANT PRIVILEGES` for this new root user with `%` as host

Comment: Now the first error is resolved, only the fatal error still appears

Comment: The fatal error means you don't have a function called "handle_error" anywhere in your code.

Comment: Its the mistake in your code. nothing to do with mysql connection string.

Comment: Thanks Suku, let me correct my code and I will update to say if its working now

Comment: @Suku, please have a look at the update I made to the script. and I am sure that database called management exists

Comment: It not really an error, I get the message 'table not found' meaning it doesnt connect to the database called management. I updated the script, please have a look at it

Answer (score 2):

1)Make sure firewall Allow  MySQL.

2)Make sure MySQL remote connection permission Allowed .

Comment: Hi I dropped the firewall and opened port 3306 on the database server

Comment: IF you are sure MySQL remote connection permission Allowed . put port address on ip (172.x1.x1.x2:3306) and check php.ini for MySQL config

Comment: Yeah! I checked it twice to ensure that permission is allowed. Now it connects to the database, but doesnt find the database called management

Comment: get Result of $conn=mysql_connect and use it on mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME,$conn) or die($table_error);  and check your MySQL user  access set correctly dont test by root user because of this user access to all DB