# Login to another server from Current server using Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

I googled a lot but did'nt find clear solution
I am trying to insert data from a

```
table1 of a database1 from server1
```

to

```
table2 of database2 from server2
```

where i am unable to login to server2 because of sqlserver authentication

1. So my question is how to connect to server2 using server authentication from server1 ??
2. Also give me simple solution to insert data from one server to another ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438544/connect-to-mysql-on-a-different-server

Comment: I WANT TO DO IT FROM SQL QUERY

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OPENROWSET` something like this ...

```
USE TargetDatabase
GO

CREATE TABLE #TempTable1(CompanyName NVARCHAR(100), City NVARCHAR(100), Country NVARCHAR(100))
GO

INSERT INTO #TempTable1(CompanyName , City , Country)
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=[SourceServer\InstanceName];Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                'SELECT CompanyName, City, Country
                 FROM Database.dbo.TableName') AS a;
GO
```